# can't get array element in success function of ajax by looping

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {

                          var keysArr = [1, 6, 8];

                          for (var i = 0; i < keysArr.length; ++i){

                              $.ajax({
                                    type:"post",
                                    dataType:"json",
                                    data:{"minVal":ranges.xaxis.from, "maxVal":ranges.xaxis.to, "sid":keysArr[i]},
                                    url:"getDataByZoom.php",

                                    cache: false,
                                    success: function(data) {

                                            data1_1 = data[0];
                                            data2_1 = data[1];
                                            data1_6 = data[0];
                                            data2_6 = data[1];
                                            data1_8 = data[0];
                                            data2_8 = data[1];

                                    }
                              });
                          }
```

The above code is running as I expected but hard-coded. Thus I used code at below to execute the same action by for loop.

However, there are few problems in the following code:

1. the result is data1_undefined when using console.log(keyval1)
2. keyVal1 = data[0], here the value of date[0] did not pass to keyVal1.

Is there anyoen know where error is? Thanks in adavance!

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {

                          var keysArr = [1, 6, 8];

                          for (var i = 0; i < keysArr.length; ++i){

                              $.ajax({
                                    type:"post",
                                    dataType:"json",
                                    data:{"minVal":ranges.xaxis.from, "maxVal":ranges.xaxis.to, "sid":keysArr[i]},
                                    url:"getDataByZoom.php",

                                    cache: false,
                                    success: function(data) {

                                            keyVal1 = 'data1_' + keysArr[i];
                        keyVal2 = 'data2_' + keysArr[i];


                                            keyVal1 = data[0];
                                            keyVal2 = data[1];

                                    }
                              });
                          }
```

Comment: Have you checked what that `i` variable is in your success callback? I bet it is something you don't expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have no closure in your for loop... Try this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < keysArr.length; ++i){
                 (function(value) {
                          $.ajax({
                                type:"post",
                                dataType:"json",
                                data:{"minVal":ranges.xaxis.from, "maxVal":ranges.xaxis.to, "sid":keysArr[value]},
                                url:"getDataByZoom.php",

                                cache: false,
                                success: function(data) {

                                        keyVal1 = 'data1_' + keysArr[value];
                    keyVal2 = 'data2_' + keysArr[value];


                                        keyVal1 = data[0];
                                        keyVal2 = data[1];

                                }
                          });
                          })(i);
                      }
```

**Edit :** What are you trying to do with keyVal1 ? With this code, you are overwriting the old value for each iteration of the loop. Why aren't you using an object like this

Initialisation of keyVal1 & keyVal2 :

```
keyVal1 = {};
keyVal2 = {};
```

Ajax Success handler :

```
success: function(data) {

                    keyVal1['data1_' + keysArr[value]] = data[0];
                    keyVal2['data2_' + keysArr[value]] = data[1];

                  }
```

Then you retrieve your value like this :
    keyVal1['data1_1']

Comment: Thanks @rohk, I have solved the first problem using your solution. However, the 2nd problem still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks again, @rohk! The code only work when varialbe name is data1_1 or data2_1.  Thus, keyVal1['data1_1'] can not be variable name.

Comment: Hi @rohk, I have find solutions by using eval('data1_'+ keysArr[value]+' =data[0]') and it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have closure inside the loop, otherwise the function you're calling on the success of the AJAX request will inherit the value of `i` from the `for` loop once it has completed.

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < keysArr.length; ++i) {
    (function(value) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{"minVal":ranges.xaxis.from, "maxVal":ranges.xaxis.to, "sid":keysArr[value]},
            url:"getDataByZoom.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                keyVal1 = 'data1_' + keysArr[value];
                keyVal2 = 'data2_' + keysArr[value];
                keyVal1 = data[0];
                keyVal2 = data[1];
            }
        });
    }) (i);
}
```

You can read more about closure within for-loops at the following Blog > http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62